# if else statement in different row

Tags: python

What does it mean when if else statement in different row,I had tried it in same row but the result is different.

```
num = 407

if num > 1:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
       
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else` statement in your code:

```
...
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
...
```

is only executed because there was no `break` in your `for loop`, because your `for loop` only breaks out if the `if` statement is `True`:

```
...
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
...
```

This would mean that writing your code like this:

```
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
```

would give you the same output, if you wrote your code like this, with the `else` statement only executing if the `if` statement was proven `False`:

```
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
       else:
           print(num,"is a prime number")
```

To read more about else statements at the end of for loops, visit:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-else-conditional-statement-with-for-loop-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation matters in Python.

Indentation refers to the spaces at the beginning of a code line. Where in other programming languages the indentation in code is for readability only, the indentation in Python is very important. Python uses indentation to indicate a block of code.

Reference this article for more information: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

I'll be happy to answer any further questions you have.